# Group and sum items from array within foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm looping through the result sets of two stored procedures, getting results within one stored procedures based on fields within the other.

The two arrays containing the results sets are `$customers` and `$subcustomers`.

```
foreach($customers as $customer)
{
      foreach($subcustomers as $subcustomer)
      {
            if($subcustomer['parent'] == $customer['id'])
            {                        
                  if($customer['innumber'] == null && $subcustomer['innumber'] != null)
                  {                       
                      $chartInboundSub['name'] = $customer['name'];
                      $chartInboundSub['label'] = $subcustomer['innumber'];
                      $chartInboundSub['countInbound'] = $customer['count'];
                      $chartInboundSub['minsInbound'] = ceil($customer['duration'] / 60);
                      $chartInboundSub['customerid'] = $customer['id'];

                      array_push($out['chartInbound'], $chartInboundSub);
                  }
            }
       }
}
```

The current output of `print_r($out['chartInbound'])` is the below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [countInbound] => 426
            [minsInbound] => 340
            [name] => Telekomm
            [label] => 01-02
            [customerid] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [countInbound] => 1
            [minsInbound] => 2
            [name] => Telekomm
            [label] => 01-02
            [customerid] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [countInbound] => 3
            [minsInbound] => 21
            [name] => Telekomm
            [label] => 080
            [customerid] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [countInbound] => 1920
            [minsInbound] => 15766
            [name] => Telekomm
            [label] => 084
            [customerid] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [countInbound] => 2332
            [minsInbound] => 17521
            [name] => Telekomm
            [label] => 084
            [customerid] => 6
        )
    ...
)
```

The above results need to be grouped by `name`, `label`, `customerid` with `countInbound` and `minsInbound` summed, so :

The desired output should be:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [countInbound] => 427
                [minsInbound] => 342
                [name] => Telekomm
                [label] => 01-02
                [customerid] => 6
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [countInbound] => 3
                [minsInbound] => 21
                [name] => Telekomm
                [label] => 080
                [customerid] => 6
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [countInbound] => 4252
                [minsInbound] => 33287
                [name] => Telekomm
                [label] => 084
                [customerid] => 6
            )
        ...
    )
```

Comment: Sorry i don't really get it, you want to sum `countInbound` and `minsInbound` when name, label and customerid are the same?

Comment: @PHPeter: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Although pieces of data can be gleaned from reverse engineering the input arrays,  it is possible to provide an answer however this question Needs Clarity.  Specifically, the [mcve] is missing populated `$customers` and `$subcustomers` arrays which can be used to generate the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work. I haven't tested the code, so I make no promises.

```
$map = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($customers as $customer)
{
      foreach($subcustomers as $subcustomer)
      {
            if($subcustomer['parent'] == $customer['id'])
            {                        
                  if($customer['innumber'] == null && $subcustomer['innumber'] != null)
                  {                       

                      $key = $customer['name'] . '/' . $subcustomer['innumber'] . '/' . $customer['id'];

                      if(isset($map[$key])) {
                            $out['chartInbound'][$map[$key]]['countInbound'] += $customer['count'];
                            $out['chartInbound'][$map[$key]]['minsInbound'] += ceil($customer['duration'] / 60);
                      }
                      else {
                          $out['chartInbound'][$i] = array(
                                  'name' => $customer['name'],
                                  'label' => $subcustomer['innumber'],
                                  'countInbound' => $customer['count'],
                                  'minsInbound' => ceil($customer['duration'] / 60),
                                  'customerid' => $customer['id'],
                          );
                          $map[$key] = $i++;
                    }
                  }
            }
       }
}
```

For every combination of `name`, `label` and `customerid` it creates a string key that has to be unique for that combination. Then it checks if there is already any data for that key (by keeping a separate list of keys and their indexes in `$out['chartInbound']`). If so it just adds the `countInbound` and `minsInbound`. If not it puts the whole `$chartInboundSub` into `$out['chartInbound']`.

Please note that this relies on the key being unique. If you for instance allow `/` in the names that might not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `foreach` loops I use the 'iterator' that every PHP array has.

Assuming the array is sorted then a single pass recording the 'current group id' will be sufficient.

I use a 'read ahead' technique that so an'if' test  is not needed to find out what to do with with the 'current record'.

[working code as 'eval.in'](https://eval.in/private/696b2ffc793efe)

The code:

```
/**
 * Output stored in here...
 */
$output = array();

// groupId consists of:   name, label, customerid

// read ahead - we need the current entry of the source array...
$currentEntry = current($source);

while ($currentEntry !== false) { // process the array / file / resultset etc.

    // start of a group... process the first record that every group has...
    $currentGroupId = getGroupId($currentEntry);
    $currentGroupCountInbound = $currentEntry['countInbound'];
    $currentGroupMinsInbound = $currentEntry['minsInbound'];

    // read the next record as we always 'read ahead' after processing a record...
    next($source);
    $currentEntry = current($source);

     while ($currentGroupId == getGroupId($currentEntry)) {
        // same group = total the values...

       $currentGroupCountInbound += $currentEntry['countInbound'];
       $currentGroupMinsInbound += $currentEntry['minsInbound'];

       // next entry in the input array - will end this group if not the same...
       next($source);
       $currentEntry = current($source);
    }

    // end of the current group -- output the information...
    // add it to an array... or whatever...
    $output[] = array('groupid' => $currentGroupId,
                       'countInbound' => $currentGroupCountInbound,
                       'minsInbound' => $currentGroupMinsInbound);
}

// show the output...
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
exit;

// ---------------------------------
function getGroupId($entry = array())
{
    if (empty($entry)) {
        return array();
    }

    return array(
        $entry['name'], $entry['label'], $entry['customerid']
    );
}
```

The output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [groupid] => Array(
                    [0] => Telekomm
                    [1] => 01-02
                    [2] => 6
                )
            [countInbound] => 427
            [minsInbound] => 342
        )

    [1] => Array(
            [groupid] => Array(
                    [0] => Telekomm
                    [1] => 080
                    [2] => 6
                )
            [countInbound] => 3
            [minsInbound] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array(
            [groupid] => Array(
                    [0] => Telekomm
                    [1] => 084
                    [2] => 6
                )
            [countInbound] => 4252
            [minsInbound] => 33287
        )
)
```