# Group and sum items from two arrays containing result sets with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm looping through the result sets of two stored procedures, getting the final results based on fields within both procedures.

Below are the two result sets:

-Get all the `customers` with or without data:

```
| id |   name  | parentID | calls | type |  // there are two types of calls:1 and 2
+----+---------+----------+-------+------+
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |  100  |   1  |  // we can have same customer with both types of calls
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |   10  |   2  |
| 16 |  Orange |     7    |   50  |   2  |  // we can have one type of call and NULL..
| 16 |  Orange |     7    |  NULL | NULL |  // ..for the same customer
|  9 | Verizon |     2    |  NULL | NULL |  
| 18 |   T&T   |    108   |   30  |   1  |  
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |  120  |   1  |
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |   60  |   2  |
| 17 | CellCom |    99    |  NULL | NULL |  // we can have a single..
|  1 | T-Mobile|    14    |   85  |   2  |  //  ..NULL or type of call..
| 34 | US-Cell |    27    |  240  |   1  |  // ..for a single customer
```

-Get all the `subcustomers` with data

```
| id |      name     | parentID | calls | type |
+----+---------------+----------+-------+------+
| 44 |     CallMe    |     8    |   20  |   1  |
| 72 |    DialNow    |    16    |    5  |   1  |
| 72 |    DialNow    |    16    |   15  |   2  |
| 13 |    Online4U   |     9    |   10  |   1  |
| 22 | TeleSolutions |     9    |   30  |   1  |
|  4 |    FonezInc   |     9    |    5  |   2  |
| 23 |  MobileSelect |     9    |   10  |   2  |
| 10 |      Digi     |    20    |  100  |   1  |
| 11 |    Vodafone   |    20    |   40  |   2  |
```

**The desired result** should be the below. If the customers have subcustomers with `calls` (subcustomer.parentID = customer.id), add these calls to the customers ones against the correct `type`, otherwise show customers with data.

```
| id |   name  | parentID | calls | type |
+----+---------+----------+-------+------+
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |  120  |   1  |
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |   10  |   2  |
| 16 |  Orange |     7    |   5   |   1  |
| 16 |  Orange |     7    |   65  |   2  |
|  9 | Verizon |     2    |   40  |   1  |
|  9 | Verizon |     2    |   15  |   2  |
| 18 |   T&T   |    108   |   30  |   1  |
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |  220  |   1  |
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |  100  |   2  |
|  1 | T-Mobile|    14    |   85  |   2  |
| 34 | US-Cell |    27    |  240  |   1  |
```

The above should be obtained using PHP.

Here's my PHP:
The two arrays containing the results sets are `$customers` and `$subcustomers`.

```
foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    foreach($subcustomers as $subcustomer)
    {
        if($subcustomer['parentID'] == $customer['id'])
        {
            if(($customer['type'] == null || $customer['type'] == "1") && $subcustomer['type'] == "1") // ??
            {
                $keyi = $customer['name'] . '/' . $subcustomer['type'] . '/' . $customer['id'];

                if(isset($mapi[$keyi])) {
                      $out['inbound'][$mapi[$keyi]]['count'] += $subcustomer['calls'];
                }
                else {
                    $out['inbound'][$ii] = array(
                            'name' => $customer['name'],
                            'label' => 'Inbound Calls',
                            'count' => $subcustomer['calls'],
                            'customerid' => $customer['id'],
                    );
                    $mapi[$keyi] = $ii++;
                }                                                                       
            }
            if(($customer['type'] == null || $customer['type'] == "2") && $subcustomer['type'] == "2") // ??
            {       
                $keyo = $customer['name'] . '/' . $subcustomer['type'] . '/' . $customer['id'];

                if(isset($mapo[$keyo])) {
                      $out['outbound'][$mapo[$keyo]]['count'] += $subcustomer['calls'];
                }
                else {
                    $out['outbound'][$io] = array(
                            'name' => $customer['name'],
                            'label' => 'Outbound Calls',
                            'count' => $subcustomer['calls'],
                            'customerid' => $customer['id'],
                    );
                    $mapo[$keyo] = $io++;
                }               
            }
        }
    }

    if($customer['calls'] != null) //outside of subcustomers foreach
    {                            
        if($customer['type'] == "1"){ 
            $chartInbound['name'] = $customer['name'];
            $chartInbound['label'] = "Inbound Calls";
            $chartInbound['count'] = $customer['calls'];
            $chartInbound['customerid'] = $customer['id'];

            array_push($out1['chart'], $chartInbound);
        }
        if($customer['type'] == "2"){
            $chartOutbound['name'] = $customer['name'];
            $chartOutbound['label'] = "Outbound Calls";
            $chartOutbound['count'] = $customer['calls'];
            $chartOutbound['customerid'] = $customer['id'];

            array_push($out1['chart'], $chartOutbound);
        }
    }
}
                $outSub['chart'] = array_merge($out['inbound'], $out['outbound']);

                $out['chart'] = array_merge($outSub['chart'], $out1['chart']);
```

The problems I faced with the above code is that it doesn't add the calls correctly, either adding to much calls or to few when checking for the null type or type 1 or type 2 call. I think the conditions or somewhere the code logic is not correct.

EDIT:

The above problem is the continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051451/group-and-sum-items-from-array-within-foreach) post.

**The output** should have the same structure as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array  //indexes should be incremented, starting from 0
        (
            [name] => Telekom
            [label] => Inbound Calls  // label = type, type 1 = Inbound Calls
            [count] => 120
            [customerid] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Telekom
            [label] => Outbound Calls // type 2 = Outbound Calls
            [count] => 10
            [customerid] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Orange
            [label] => Inbound Calls
            [count] => 5
            [customerid] => 16
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Orange
            [label] => Outbound Calls
            [count] => 65
            [customerid] => 16
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Verizon
            [label] => Inbound Calls
            [count] => 40
            [id] => 9
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Verizon
            [label] => Outbound Calls
            [count] => 15
            [customerid] => 9
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => T&T
            [label] => Inbound Calls
            [count] => 30
            [id] => 18
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sprint
            [label] => Inbound Calls
            [count] => 220
            [customerid] => 20
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sprint
            [label] => Outbound Calls
            [count] => 100
            [customerid] => 20
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => T-Mobile
            [label] => Outbound Calls
            [count] => 85
            [customerid] => 1
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => US-Cell
            [label] => Inbound Calls
            [count] => 240
            [customerid] => 34
        )
)
```

Comment: Is possible to create another associative array with different structure or you must maintain the original array?

Comment: the end result array should have the same structure

Comment: Why T&T is not in the final result?

Comment: Are those tables in a database?? I'm asking because, if yes, I would like to suggest that you let the database do the work.

Comment: @Lipsyor: you're right, I've added it....

Comment: @haffla: actually no, these are the result of two stored procedures....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to group `subcustomers` and `customers` in temporary associative arrays with `parentID` and `ID` as keys. After I can built the result.

First of all I create a temporary array with subcustomers data. This array contains calls grouped by parentId (first level) and call type (second level):

```
[parentID] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [calls] => //calls of type 1
                [duration] => //duration of type 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [calls] => //calls of type 2
                [duration] => //duration of type 2
            )
    )
```

Here the code:

```
$tempS = array();

foreach($subcustomers as $subcustomer) {
    $parentId = $subcustomer['parentID'];
    $calls    = $subcustomer['calls'];
    $type     = $subcustomer['type'];
    $duration = $subcustomer['duration'];

    //if id/type is insered yet
    if(array_key_exists($parentId, $tempS) && array_key_exists($type, $tempS[$parentId])) {
        $tempS[$parentId][$type]['calls'] += $calls;
        $tempS[$parentId][$type]['duration'] += $duration;
    } else {
        $tempS[$parentId][$type]['calls'] = $calls;
        $tempS[$parentId][$type]['duration'] = $duration;
    }    
}
```

Now I create a second temporary array with customer data. The structure of this array is like this:

```
[id] => Array
    (
        [name] => 'Telekom'
        [parentID] => 80
        [calls] => Array
            (
                [1] => //calls of type 1
                [2] => //calls of type 2
            )
        [duration] => Array
            (
                [1] => //duration of type 1
                [2] => //duration of type 2
            )
    )
```

Here the code:

```
$tempC = array();

foreach($customers as $customer) {
    $id       = $customer['id'];
    $name     = $customer['name'];
    $parentId = $customer['parentID'];
    $calls    = $customer['calls'];
    $type     = $customer['type'];
    $duration = $customer['duration'];

    //if id/type is insered yet
    if(array_key_exists($id, $tempC) && array_key_exists('calls', $tempC[$id]) && array_key_exists($type, $tempC[$id]['calls'])) {
        if($calls!=null){
            $tempC[$id]['calls'][$type] += $calls;
            $tempC[$id]['duration'][$type] += $duration;
        }
    } else {
        if($calls!=null){
            $tempC[$id]['calls'][$type] = $calls;
            $tempC[$id]['duration'][$type] = $duration;
        }
        $tempC[$id]['name'] = $name;
        $tempC[$id]['parentID'] = $parentId;
    }
}
```

Temporary arrays are calculated correctly even in the presence of duplicate rows in the set returned by the stored procedure. See the example above:

```
| id |   name  | parentID | calls | type | duration |
+----+---------+----------+-------+------+----------+
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |  100  |   1  |     3150 | 
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |   10  |   1  |      250 |
```

Note that in this case will be done the sum of calls of the same type (110) and the sum of seconds (3400).

At this point I can compute the result array:

```
$result = array();

foreach($tempC as $id => $customer) {

    $type1 = 1; $type2 = 2;
    $type1label = "Inbound Calls";
    $type2label = "Outbound Calls";

    $type1Call = 0;
    $type2Call = 0;
    $type1Duration = 0;
    $type2Duration = 0;

    if(array_key_exists('calls', $customer) && array_key_exists($type1, $customer['calls'])) {
        $type1Call += $customer['calls'][$type1];
        $type1Duration += $customer['duration'][$type1];
    }
    if(array_key_exists($id, $tempS) && array_key_exists($type1, $tempS[$id])) {
        $type1Call += $tempS[$id][$type1]['calls'];
        $type1Duration += $tempS[$id][$type1]['duration'];
    }
    if($type1Call>0) {
        $result[] = [
            'name' => $customer['name'],
            'label' => $type1label,
            'count' => $type1Call,
            'mins' => ceil($type1Duration / 60),
            'customerid' => $id
        ];
    }

    if(array_key_exists('calls', $customer) && array_key_exists($type2, $customer['calls'])) {
        $type2Call += $customer['calls'][$type2];
        $type2Duration += $customer['duration'][$type2];
    }
    if(array_key_exists($id, $tempS) && array_key_exists($type2, $tempS[$id])) {
        $type2Call += $tempS[$id][$type2];
        $type2Duration += $tempS[$id][$type2]['duration'];
    }
    if($type2Call>0) {
        $result[] = [
            'name' => $customer['name'],
            'label' => $type2label,
            'count' => $type2Call,
            'mins' => ceil($type2Duration / 60),
            'customerid' => $id
        ];
    }   
}
```

Note that you may use `uasort()` method on `$tempC` before compute the result to obtain an ordered-by customer name result.

Comment: I edited the locig of the algorithm to fit a missunderstanding (based on T&T case)

Comment: I tried your code. The output of `$tempC` and `$tempS` seem to contain correct data. But the final `$result` does not - it doesn't seem to add everything. Please see my edit with the desired output. If you can change it to look like that, would be great.

Comment: Result had to have sum of customer and subcustomer calls, excluding nulls. Is it true? I'll check code later

Comment: I found a little issue in my code.
Type is always 1 or 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95940/discussion-between-lipsyor-and-alex).

Comment: I've forgot to add the `duration` field to the input result sets. I tried to do it but didn't manage. It should be computed exactly like the `calls`. (difference being that duration are seconds and should be converted to minutes). Haven't updated my post yet. Please see my edit on your post. Thanks.

Comment: What if the call `type` is dynamic, e.g. more than 10 types? I' ll create a new post of needed. Thanks.

Comment: Temporary arrays are still the same. The costruction of result array will be modified with arrays instrad of single variables (type, typelabel, calls, duration...)

Comment: will that work with dynamic types and labels? i.e. we don't know what call types there will be?

Comment: I will create a new post with this in a couple of minutes

Comment: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947465/group-and-sum-items-from-two-arrays