# Group and sum items from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm looping through the result sets of two stored procedures, getting the final results based on fields within both procedures.

Below are the two result sets:

-Get all the `$customers` with or without data:

```
| id |   name  | parentID | calls | duration |  type | 
+----+---------+----------+-------+----------+-------+
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |  100  |   3000   | 01-02 |  
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |   10  |    700   |   080 |
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |    5  |    100   |    05 |
| 16 |  Orange |     7    |   50  |   2200   |    03 |
| 16 |  Orange |     7    | NULL  |   NULL   |  NULL |
|  9 | Verizon |     2    | NULL  |   NULL   |  NULL |  
| 18 |   T&T   |    108   |   30  |   1200   |    04 |  
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |  120  |   4000   |    09 | 
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |   60  |   3500   | 01-02 |
| 17 | CellCom |    99    | NULL  |   NULL   |  NULL | 
|  1 | T-Mobile|    14    |   85  |   2600   |   087 | 
|  1 | T-Mobile|    14    |    2  |     30   |    07 |
| 34 | US-Cell |    27    |  240  |   1700   |   084 |
```

-Get all the `$subcustomers` with data

```
| id |      name     | parentID | calls | duration |  type | 
+----+---------------+----------+-------+----------+-------+
| 44 |     CallMe    |     8    |   20  |   400    | 01-02 |
| 44 |     CallMe    |     8    |    5  |    20    |   080 |
| 44 |     CallMe    |     8    |   15  |   200    |   087 |
| 72 |    DialNow    |    16    |  100  |  2000    |    03 |
| 72 |    DialNow    |    16    |    5  |   100    |    04 |
| 13 |    Online4U   |     9    |   10  |    25    |    05 |
| 22 | TeleSolutions |     9    |   30  |   200    |    05 |
|  4 |    FonezInc   |     9    |    5  |     5    |   084 |
| 10 |      Digi     |    20    |  100  |  4000    |    09 |
| 11 |    Vodafone   |    20    |   40  |  2400    |    08 |
```

**The desired result** should be as follows:

-Add all calls/duration of subcustomers to the customers ones (if subcustomer.parentID = customer.id), against the correct `type`, otherwise show customers with data. 
 -If a customer has no calls/type (NULL) and has subcustomers with calls, add these to the customer. 
 -If a subcustomer has different types of calls, add these to the customer also
 -The types are dynamic, we don't now what/how many types there will be
Like below:

```
| id |   name  | parentID | calls | duration |  type | 
+----+---------+----------+-------+----------+-------+
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |  120  |    3400  | 01-02 |
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |   15  |     720  |   080 |
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |    5  |     100  |    05 |
|  8 | Telekom |    80    |   15  |     200  |   087 |
| 16 |  Orange |     7    |  150  |    4200  |    03 |
| 16 |  Orange |     7    |    5  |     100  |    04 |
|  9 | Verizon |     2    |   40  |     225  |    05 |
|  9 | Verizon |     2    |    5  |       5  |   084 |
| 18 |   T&T   |    108   |   30  |    1200  |    04 |
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |  220  |    4000  |    09 |
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |   60  |    3500  | 01-02 |
| 20 |  Sprint |    33    |   40  |    2400  |    08 |
|  1 | T-Mobile|    14    |   85  |   2600   |   087 | 
|  1 | T-Mobile|    14    |    2  |     30   |    07 |
| 34 | US-Cell |    27    |  240  |   1700   |   084 |
```

An idea is to group `subcustomers` and `customers` in temporary associative arrays with `parentID` and `ID` as keys. After that we can built the result.

**Input 1**: [Here's some dummy data](https://jsfiddle.net/4sj680u2/1/) for the temporary **subcustomers** array.
 
This array contains calls grouped by parentId (first level) and call type (second level). It has the following structure:

```
[parentID] => Array
    (
        [type] => Array  // e.g. type = 03
            (
                [calls] => value  //calls of type 03
                [duration] => value  //duration of type 03
            )
        [type] => Array //e.g. type = 087
            (
                [calls] => value  //calls of type 087
                [duration] => value  //duration of type 087
            )
         ...
    )
```

Below is the code that creates the temp. subcustomers array:

```
$tempS = array();

foreach($subcustomers as $subcustomer) {
    $parentId = $subcustomer['parentID'];
    $calls    = $subcustomer['calls'];
    $type     = $subcustomer['type'];
    $duration = $subcustomer['duration'];

    //if id/type is insered yet
    if(array_key_exists($parentId, $tempS) && array_key_exists($type, $tempS[$parentId])) {
        $tempS[$parentId][$type]['calls'] += $calls;
        $tempS[$parentId][$type]['duration'] += $duration;
    } else {
        $tempS[$parentId][$type]['calls'] = $calls;
        $tempS[$parentId][$type]['duration'] = $duration;
    }    
}
```

**Input 2**: [Here's dummy data](https://jsfiddle.net/f4bekk81/) for the temp. **customers** array. The structure of this array is as follows:

```
[id] => Array    
    (
        [name] => 'Telekom'
        [parentID] => 80
        [calls] => Array
            (
                [type] => // e.g. calls of type 01-02
                [type] => // e.g. calls of type 05
            )
        [duration] => Array
            (
                [type] => //duration of type 01-02
                [type] => //duration of type 05
            )
    )
```

Here's the code for the temp. customers array:

```
$tempC = array();

foreach($customers as $customer) {
    $id       = $customer['id'];
    $name     = $customer['name'];
    $parentId = $customer['parentID'];
    $calls    = $customer['calls'];
    $type     = $customer['type'];
    $duration = $customer['duration'];

    //if id/type is insered yet
    if(array_key_exists($id, $tempC) && array_key_exists($type, $tempC[$id])) {
            $tempC[$id]['calls'][$type] += $calls;
            $tempC[$id]['duration'][$type] += $duration;
        } else {
            //if subcustomer has calls of that type
            if(array_key_exists($customerId, $tempS) && array_key_exists($type, $tempS[$customerId])) {
                $tempC[$id]['calls'][$type] = $tempS[$id][$type] + $calls;
                $tempC[$id]['duration'][$type] = $tempS[$id][$type] + $duration;
            } else {
                $tempC[$id]['calls'][$type] = $calls;
                $tempC[$id]['duration'][$type] = $duration;
            }
        $tempC[$id]['name'] = $name;
        $tempC[$id]['parentID'] = $parentId;
    }
}
```

Having these two temp. arrays we should compute the result array.

**The output** should have the same structure as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array  //indexes should be incremented, starting from 0
        (
            [name] => Telekom
            [label] => 01-02  //label = type
            [count] => 120
            [mins] => 3400
            [customerid] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Telekom
            [label] => 080
            [count] => 15
            [mins] => 720  // mins = (duration / 60)
            [customerid] => 8
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Telekom
            [label] => 05
            [count] => 5
            [mins] => 100
            [customerid] => 8
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Telekom
            [label] => 087
            [count] => 15
            [mins] => 200
            [customerid] => 8
        )


    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Orange
            [label] => 03
            [count] => 150
            [mins] => 4200
            [customerid] => 16
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Orange
            [label] => 04
            [count] => 5
            [mins] => 100
            [customerid] => 16
        )
    ....

)
```

I've tried:

```
$result = array();

foreach($tempC as $id => $customer) {

        $type = key($customer['calls']); // ??
        $calls = 0;
        $duration = 0;

        //sums calls of customer
        if(array_key_exists('calls', $customer) && array_key_exists($type, $customer['calls'])) {
            $calls += $customer['calls'][$type];
            $duration += $customer['duration'][$type];
        }
        //sums calls of subcustomer
        if(array_key_exists($id, $tempS) && array_key_exists($type, $tempS[$id])) {
            $calls += $tempS[$id][$type]['calls'];
            $duration += $tempS[$id][$type]['duration'];
        }
        //if there are calls, put in the result array
        if($calls>0) {
            $result[] = [
                'name' => $customer['name'],
                'label' => $type,
                'count' => $calls,
                'mins' => ceil($duration/ 60),
                'customerid' => $id
            ];
        }
}
```

But the above code to get the final result array is not correct somewhere because it doesn't add all the calls and types correctly.

Note: this post was created with the help of user @Lipsyor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may collect types in the array `$types` while creating the temporary arrays.

First of all declare the array:

```
$types = array();
```

in each `forach(...)` for `$customers` and `$subcustomers` insert:

```
$types[$type] = true;
```

Note that I use the key of the array to store type name: using this trick you never insert duplicates in the array.

Here the code for the creation of the result array:

```
$result = array();

foreach($tempC as $id => $customer) {

    foreach ($types as $type => $value) {

        $call = 0;
        $duration = 0;

        if(array_key_exists('calls', $customer) && array_key_exists($type, $customer['calls'])) {
            $call += $customer['calls'][$type];
            $duration += $customer['duration'][$type];
        }
        if(array_key_exists($id, $tempS) && array_key_exists($type, $tempS[$id])) {
            $call += $tempS[$id][$type]['calls'];
            $duration += $tempS[$id][$type]['duration'];
        }
        if($call>0) {
            $result[] = [
                'name' => $customer['name'],
                'label' => $type,
                'count' => $call,
                'mins' => ceil($duration / 60),
                'customerid' => $id
            ];
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: please see my edit on your post (commented below code and last part with edit)